# Ways to share a "Top X" list between two Drupal websites?

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to come up with some easy methods to share data between two Drupal websites. Here's my situation: Two websites both want a Top X Music listing with images, audio and data. One website is already creating and updating this list, and since they both use the same list the other website wants to straight up "steal" the first list, content, style and all. They want to take advantage of the work done to create the list on the other website. Their websites are structurally similar, and we control both sites. Audio is made playable using SWF tools.

Domain isn't really an appropriate solution here as the two sites share nothing besides the Top X Music list. I am able to create a view on the original site to feed the data in any format I want.

Some solutions I've been considering are:

- Feed the data from one site to the other, hard link back to the other
  site for audio/images.
- iFrame the data on the site that is "stealing"
  the list. (easy but seems too crude!)
- jQuery AJAX load the data on the "stealing" site.

Basically I'm looking for suggestions of how you might handle this if they were your Drupal websites. I am familiar with Feeds, but would need to write a parser specifically for this feed, which seems like overkill for something so simple. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Drupal you're using on the two sites. Assuming it's Drupal 6, you may want to check out the [Web Widgets](http://drupal.org/project/web_widgets) module and/or the [Embed widgets](http://drupal.org/project/embed_widgets) module.

Comment: It's Drupal 6. Thanks for your suggestions, it looks like they might work. I'll give them a try today.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after a list of content from SiteA you could add a display to a given view and get RSS output. The [ViewsRSS](http://drupal.org/project/views_rss) module gives you more control over what is returned.

If you're looking for more of a widget approach then I'd start looking at the Web widgets or Embed widgets modules. They're ok for basic functionality, but if you're looking to want more functionality I'd consider either embedding the content in an iframe (quick and dirty) or reviewing the [services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module(s) - although this may be overkill for your needs.

HTH.